# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with AMI2 and docker-compose.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I have been trying to make Elastic Beanstalk work with Docker AMI2 image and `docker-compose.yml`.
The documentation says it should work out of the box with `docker-compose.yml` file.
I use ECR as docker registry and have updated Elastic Beanstalk role to be able to pull images from ECR.
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html

> Create a docker-compose.yml file to deploy a Docker image from a hosted repository to Elastic Beanstalk. No other files are required if all your deployments are sourced from images in public repositories. (If your deployment must source an image from a private repository, you need to include additional configuration files for authentication. For more information, see Using images from a private repository.) For more information about the docker-compose.yml file, see Compose file reference on the Docker website.

However, I keep getting the following message when spinning up the environment:

> Instance deployment: You must specify a Docker image in either 'Dockerfile' or 'Dockerrun.aws.json' in your source bundle. The deployment failed.

According to documentation `Dockerrun.aws.json` should only be required for the old AMI. Has anyone come across similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. The documentation states `docker-compose.yml` is the only file needed but it still needs to be zipped before being uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: Hi, testing this now, but I'm confused by the conflicting documentation: "If you use only a docker-compose.yml file to deploy your application, you don't need to create a .zip file."

Further, you also used to be able to just upload a Dockerrun.Aws.json directly, without zipping, so I was expecting the same behavior.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had some similar issues when migrating to docker-compose file from the dockerrun.json file.

What I did was to basically create a new app on elastic beanstalk and ***specify the Amazon Linux 2 platform under Docker as deployement option.***

Below I will attach my docker-compose.yaml file and also the Github workflow with the part of deploying to ELB if you are interested (Or if it might help someone else)

Docker-compose.yaml, you will need to either remove the image or insert your own image tag url.

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    image: <IMG-TAG here e.g from ECR repository>
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

github.yaml

```
  deploy-staging:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: |
          zip -r deploy.zip *
      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v9
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: test
          environment_name: test
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          region: eu-north-1
          deployment_package: deploy.zip
          use_existing_version_if_available: true
```